# Cannot read property 'Nome"' of undefined at Object.eval [as updateDirectives]

Tags: sql, .net, asp.net, angular

Estou fazendo um Asp.Net Core Web API com Angular 7 CRUD e estou tendo problema na fase final, logo quando entro no meu localhost do angular e abro o console, me deparo com o seguinte log (Observaçao, ja olhei no SQL Studio Managment e a Coluna está criada com esse nome mesmo)

```
PaymentDetailComponent.html:11 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'CardOwner' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (PaymentDetailComponent.html:11)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:23911)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:23307)
    at callViewAction (core.js:23548)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:23490)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:23313)
    at callViewAction (core.js:23548)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:23490)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:23313)
    at callViewAction (core.js:23548)
View_PaymentDetailComponent_0 @ PaymentDetailComponent.html:11
```

Seguem os códigos: caso necessário eu edito a pergunta adicionando o que mais voces pedirem.

```
public class PaymentDetails
    {   
        //Propriedades do PaymentDetails
        //Aparentemente usamos isso para criar um banco
        //Usando alguns comandon NuGet Package Manager (Comand Line)
        //Inicializaremos o banco no SQLServer Express
        [Key]
        public int PMId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Column(TypeName ="nvarchar(100)")]
        public string CardOwner { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(16)")]
        public string CardNumber { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(5)")]
        public string ExpirationDate { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(3)")]
        public string CVV { get; set;}
    }
```

```
export class PaymentDetail {

    PMId: number;
    CardOwner: string;
    CardNumber: string;
    ExpirationDate: string;
    CVV: string;

}
```

```
<input name="CardOwner" #CardOwner="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="service.formData.CardOwner" 
    type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="CardOwner" required maxlength="100">
```

Se eu faço isso de tirar o .formData. do codigo, ele funciona consideralvelmente. Algumas funçoes falham

```
<input name="CardOwner" #CardOwner="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="service.CardOwner" 
   type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="CardOwner" required maxlength="100">
```

Comment: Parece que seu formData está indefinido

Comment: Perdão pela demora, mas eu defini ele nos serviços

Comment: Se eu tiro os formData, o código funciona, mas apenas para inserção

Comment: Melhor mover ele pro componente e definir ele onInit

Comment: Mas, no video que estou vendo o cara faz exatamente esses passos... isso que me deixa meio desanimado